# Tail recursive JSON constructor

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion, tail-recursion

I have a directory structure from NPM package '[directory-tree](https://github.com/mihneadb/node-directory-tree)' that I would like to flatten into a simpler nested structure. I want a tail recursive solution to convert the first object into the second, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to construct it.

Of course the primary conditional is whether or not a 'node' in the first structure is a 'file' or a 'directory'. If it's a file, we simply want the basename of the file to key the relative path. However, if it's a directory, we want the basename of the directory to key an object and recurse down frome there.

I'll use their example to illustrate the structure:

```js
{
  "path": "photos",
  "name": "photos",
  "size": 600,
  "type": "directory",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "photos/summer",
      "name": "summer",
      "size": 400,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "photos/summer/june",
          "name": "june",
          "size": 400,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg",
              "name": "windsurf.jpg",
              "size": 400,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "photos/winter",
      "name": "winter",
      "size": 200,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "photos/winter/january",
          "name": "january",
          "size": 200,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/ski.png",
              "name": "ski.png",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".png"
            },
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg",
              "name": "snowboard.jpg",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like the final structure to be much simpler. Something like the following:

```js
{
    "photos": {
        "summer": {
            "june": {
                "windsurf.jpg": "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg"
            }
        },
        "winter": {
            "january": {
                "ski.png": "photos/winter/january/ski.png",
                "snowboard.jpg": "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any advantage of your "simple" structure. And i dont think that its possible to use tail call recursion here.

Comment: Why are you concerned with reshaping your data? Your proposed result is substantially worse than the original due to value-based keys. What will you do with the data after you reshape it? Display a list of files and directories? Search for files matching a string? That is your real question, not whatever you wrote here.

Comment: Sorry, I asked a technical question. Not advice on how to write my program. My real question is **exactly** as I have wrote and worded it. The thing with StackOverflow my friend, is that if you write a question on style or algorithmic approach, it's 'too general' and will be ignored or removed. If you write a question that's too idiosyncratic or library specific, it won't get any views. Please trust that some of us know this site isn't a place for CS101 kids to get advice on their homework. I don't need to explain what my program does and why this data structure needs to be the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert a depth-first search to tail-recursion for your case.

```js
let testObj = {
  "path": "photos",
  "name": "photos",
  "size": 600,
  "type": "directory",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "photos/summer",
      "name": "summer",
      "size": 400,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "photos/summer/june",
          "name": "june",
          "size": 400,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg",
              "name": "windsurf.jpg",
              "size": 400,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "photos/winter",
      "name": "winter",
      "size": 200,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "photos/winter/january",
          "name": "january",
          "size": 200,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/ski.png",
              "name": "ski.png",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".png"
            },
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg",
              "name": "snowboard.jpg",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function tailRecurse(stack, result){
  if (!stack.length)
    return result;
    
  // stack will contain
  // the next object to examine
  [obj, ref] = stack.pop();

  if (obj.type == 'file'){
    ref[obj.name] = obj.path;
      
  } else if (obj.type == 'directory'){
    ref[obj.name] = {};
    
    for (let child of obj.children)
      stack.push([child, ref[obj.name]]);
  }
  
  return tailRecurse(stack, result);
}


// Initialise
let _result = {};
let _stack = [[testObj, _result]];

console.log(tailRecurse(_stack, _result));
```

Comment: Very elegant passing by reference.... I wouldn't have thought to do that.

Comment: @W4t3randWind thanks! That kind of stack implementation is often seen just as a `while (stack.length)` loop. Making it an explicit recursion is just another way of running the same thing really :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function copyNode(node, result = {}){
   if(node.type === "directory"){
      const folder = result[node.name] = {};
      for(const sub of node.children)
           copyNode(sub, folder);

  } else {
      result[node.name] = node.path;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This is a simple recursive approach, this is not tail call recursive as it is very difficult ( = not worth it ) to traverse a tree with only one tail call.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach by chekcing the type.

For `'directory'` take an object and iterate the children.

Otherwise assign the path to the key with the given name.

```js
function fn(source, target) {
    if (source.type === 'directory') {
        target[source.name] = {};
        (source.children || []).forEach(o => fn(o, target[source.name]));
    } else {
        target[source.name] = source.path;
    }
}

var source = { path: "photos", name: "photos", size: 600, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/summer", name: "summer", size: 400, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/summer/june", name: "june", size: 400, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg", name: "windsurf.jpg", size: 400, type: "file", extension: ".jpg" }] }] }, { path: "photos/winter", name: "winter", size: 200, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/winter/january", name: "january", size: 200, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/winter/january/ski.png", name: "ski.png", size: 100, type: "file", extension: ".png" }, { path: "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg", name: "snowboard.jpg", size: 100, type: "file", extension: ".jpg" }] }] }] },
    target = {};

fn(source, target);
    
console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```